# How to create a read-only textbox in ASP.NET MVC4 Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using

```
 <td>@Html.TextBoxFor("code",new { @readonly="readonly" })</td>
```

but getting an error. What is the right syntax?

The error:

```
Error   1   The type arguments for method 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.TextBoxFor<TModel,TProperty>(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,TProperty>>, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,object>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.  c:\Users\ATPL\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\AST_MGMT\AST_MGMT\Views\Department\Add.cshtml   7   18  AST_MGMT
```

Comment: Specify the types.  `TextBoxFor<string,object>` (am assuming such exists)

Comment: I believe the problem is with your string literal "code" and not the `readonly`.  This requires a lambda which relates it to your model. For example, if you have a property called `code`, `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.code, new { @readonly="readonly" })`

Comment: on doing such shoing an error CS1963: An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have a model in your view, you can use something like this where "model" represents your model:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.code, new { @readonly="readonly" })
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try `<td>@Html.TextBox("code",new { @readonly="readonly" })</td>`, when using `TextBoxFor` you need to pass a property from the **ViewModel** with a lambda expression.

Answer (score 1):

For `@Html.TextBoxFor()` use:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.code, new { @readonly="readonly" })
```

For `@Html.TextBox()` use:

```
@Html.TextBox("code", "default value ", new { @readonly="readonly" })
```